# How to wrap text around a TikZ image?

Tags: tikz-pgf, wrapfigure

I'm trying to wrap text around a TikZ image using the `wrapfigure` package, but it doesn't seem to be working--the document compiles, but the image is pushed down with new text. The error I get on the log is that `wrapfigure` is being used in a conflicting environment. I'm not quite sure how to resolve this and I would appreciate any help.

Here's my code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{outlines}
\usepackage{tensor}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage[top=2cm, bottom=1.3cm, left=3cm, right=2.0cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
\section*{Chapter 3 Problems}
\begin{outline}[enumerate]
  \1 A car is driven 215 km west and then 85 km southwest. What is the displacement of the car from the point of origin (magnitude and direction)? Draw a diagram.
  \begin{wrapfigure}{l}{0.5cm}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[<->,thick] (-3,0) -- (1,0);
    \draw[<->,thick] (0,-2) -- (0,1);
    \draw[step=0.25cm,gray,very thin] (-3,-2) grid (1,1);
    \draw[red,very thick,<-] (-2,0) -- (0,0);
    \draw (-1,0.15) node [font=\tiny] {215 km};
    \draw[blue,very thick,->] (-2,0) -- (-2.5591,-1);
    \draw (-2.1,-0.5) node [rotate=57,font=\tiny] {85 km};
    \draw (-2.22,0) arc (180:225:0.3);
    \draw[black,thick,->] (0,0) -- (-2.5591,-1);
    \draw (-1,0) arc (180:225:0.5);
    \draw[orange,very thick,dashed] (-2.5591,0) -- (-2.5591,-1);
    \draw[green,very thick,dashed] (-2,0) -- (-2.5591,0);
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{wrapfigure}
    \2 [] Displacement in the \textit{y}:
      \3 [] \textit{D}$_y$  
\end{outline}

\end{document}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't think you can use `wrapfigure` inside `outline` or similar enumerate environments. This is basically what the "conflicting environment" is most likely about.

Comment: Okay, I'll take it out of the `outline` environment to see if `wrapfigure` will work (although I needed it there).

Comment: So `outline` does conflict with `wrapfigure`...

Answer (score 3):

You can use  `picins` instead of `wrapfig`  but like `outlines` `picins` is not in texLive.

I use

```
  \parpic[r]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    ...
```

with your example.